# How to change an refrech a property in a form from another one in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm trying to change the 'enabled' property in Form1 from Form2. the enabled property is public in Form1 so I can access to it and change its value from another form. However, nothing happens, I think I must "refrech" the Form1 to update changes. How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could wrap the enabled property in a method and in that method also refresh the form. something like public void ToggleEnabled(bool value){this.enabled = value; Refresh();}

Comment: What do you mean by `nothing happens`? According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if the `Enabled` property is set after the form is visible, it will change the `Enabled` property of the form's minimize, maximize, close and system buttons. Are you changing it **after** the form is shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use events. Create some event in child form (form2, form3 ... etc), then when you create create form2,3,4,... subscribe to event.

```
// form1 code
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.SomeChangePropertyEvent += f_SomeChangePropertyEvent;
        f.ShowDialog(this);
    }

    private void f_SomeChangePropertyEvent(bool obj)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = obj;
    }
//form2 code
    public event Action<bool> SomeChangePropertyEvent; 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var h = SomeChangePropertyEvent;
        if (h != null)
            h(false); // I'll set false, you can't something else :)
    }
```